Simulating people talking to each other in a network
I have this network graph in R:
library(igraph)

set.seed(123)

n <- 20
g <- sample_gnm(n, m = n * 2, directed = FALSE)

while (!is_connected(g)) {
    # Find disconnected components
    components <- components(g)
    

    for (i in 2:components$no) {
        from <- sample(which(components$membership == i), 1)
        to <- sample(which(components$membership == 1), 1)
        g <- add_edges(g, c(from, to))
    }
}

g <- simplify(g, remove.multiple = FALSE, remove.loops = TRUE)

V(g)$weight <- runif(vcount(g))

layout <- layout_with_fr(g)

par(mfrow = c(1, 2), mar = c(1, 1, 1, 1))
plot(g, layout = layout, edge.arrow.size = 0.1, 
     vertex.label = V(g)$name, vertex.size = 15, 
     vertex.label.color = "black", edge.curved = 0,
     vertex.color = "white", edge.color = "black",
     main = "Connected Graph with Node Labels")

plot(g, layout = layout, edge.arrow.size = 0.1, 
     vertex.label = round(V(g)$weight, 2), vertex.size = 15, 
     vertex.label.color = "black", edge.curved = 0,
     vertex.color = "white", edge.color = "black",
     main = "Connected Graph with Node Weights")


I am trying to create a node communication scenario in which nodes sequentially communicate with each other:

Each node is a person that starts with a weight between 0 and 1
To begin with, a given node averages all the weights of its neighbors and the weight of itself and thereby updates its own weight
Then, the neighbors of this node do the same thing with their neighbors
This continues until 100 communications have taken place

E.g.

communication 1: 16 with  6 and 19
communication 2: 6 with 16, 19, 8, 14
communication 3: 19 with 16,6,4
communication 4: 14 with 6,11,5,9,8
etc.

Eventually, the same node will be updated more than once (e.g. when we reach node 18 and node 13, how do we reverse and start the communication in the other direction).
I tried to do this with the following code (we randomly sample a node each time):
library(igraph)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

# Function to update a single node's weight
update_node_weight <- function(g, node) {
    neighbors <- neighbors(g, node)
    neighbor_weights <- V(g)$weight[neighbors]
    new_weight <- mean(c(V(g)$weight[node], neighbor_weights))
    return(new_weight)
}

# Function to simulate communication process
simulate_communication <- function(g, num_iterations) {
    weight_history <- matrix(nrow = vcount(g), ncol = num_iterations + 1)
    weight_history[, 1] <- V(g)$weight
    
    for (i in 1:num_iterations) {
        node <- sample(V(g), 1)
        V(g)$weight[node] <- update_node_weight(g, node)
        weight_history[, i + 1] <- V(g)$weight
        
        cat("Communication", i, ": Node", node, "with", paste(neighbors(g, node), collapse = ", "), "\n")
    }
    
    return(list(graph = g, weight_history = weight_history))
}

plot_graph_weights <- function(g, layout, weights, main_title) {
    plot(g, layout = layout, edge.arrow.size = 0.1,
         vertex.label = round(weights, 2), vertex.size = 15,
         vertex.label.color = "black", edge.curved = 0,
         vertex.color = "white", edge.color = "black",
         main = main_title)
}

I then ran the simulation:
num_iterations <- 100
result <- simulate_communication(g, num_iterations)

Finally, I tried to plot it:
weight_df <- as.data.frame(t(result$weight_history))
colnames(weight_df) <- paste0("Node", 1:vcount(g))
weight_df$Communication <- 0:num_iterations

avg_weights <- rowMeans(weight_df[, 1:vcount(g)])
avg_weight_df <- data.frame(Communication = 0:num_iterations, AverageWeight = avg_weights)

ggplot_avg <- ggplot(avg_weight_df, aes(x = Communication, y = AverageWeight)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(title = "Average Weight of All Nodes Over Communications",
         x = "Communication",
         y = "Average Weight")

print(ggplot_avg)

weight_long <- melt(weight_df, id.vars = "Communication", variable.name = "Node", value.name = "Weight")

ggplot_evolution <- ggplot(weight_long, aes(x = Communication, y = Weight, color = Node)) +
    geom_line() +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(title = "Evolution of Node Weights Over Communications",
         x = "Communication",
         y = "Weight") +
    theme(legend.position = "none")  

print(ggplot_evolution)


sequence of node visits

how do we reverse and start the communication in the other direction

Picking each node at random will produce artifacts,
as not every node will be visited the identical number
of times. There will be a distribution, with some out
there in the tail, getting more visits at the expense
of less lucky nodes.
Merely iterating over sequential labels can also produce
artifacts, especially if numerically close labels are
close to one another in the graph.
Prefer to make several complete passes over the graph.
At start of pass, produce a list of labels, and
shuffle
it to produce the randomly permuted order for visits.
On the next pass across the entire graph,
produce a brand new permutation.
Repeat until enough communications have happened.
This lets you hang onto the following assignment:
        V(g)$weight[node] <- update_node_weight(g, node)

batch updates
That weight update above is combining means from nodes
of different degree, in arbitrary orders.
To make it easier to see convergence,
consider computing and storing one full pass worth of update
statistics off on the side, and finish the pass by using
those stats to update all node weights.
I think this should give us monotonic convergence
at each node, kind of like water finding a new level.
Then discard (re-init) the accumulated stats,
and begin a new batched pass over the whole graph.
Order of visits doesn't matter, so no need for a shuffle.
This is not unlike a
Life
implementation doing double-buffering
between "old" and "new" grids
when computing which nodes / cells shall be
alive in the next generation.
By allocating extra storage and making readonly
access to the "old" setup, we prevent
mutations from interfering with adjacent
node calculations.

thank you J_H! Do you think my R code looks ok?
